# How to display label of a field in qweb reports?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb

Is there a way to display the label we put on a field in a qweb reports?

For example

In my .py

```
findings = fields.Text(string="Findings")
```

And in my .xml

```
<t t-esc="findings" /> <!-- only shows the value -->
```

Can we also get the label in qweb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the label of the field.
Instead you can add ***html*** tag to show the label

Ex:

```
<p>Your Label <t t-esc="findings" /> </p>

 or
<span> Some Text <t t-esc="findings" /> </span>
```

Comment: it is very disappointing to not be able to have the label from the field in qweb reports

Answer (score 1):

You can get field description (label) using a function but I encourage you to display labels as they did in odoo [invoice reports](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml#L28).

To get `date_invoice` label:

```
def get_field_label(self, model_name, field_name):
    ir_model_obj = self.env['ir.model']
    ir_model_fields_obj = self.env['ir.model.fields']
    model_id = ir_model_obj.search([('model', '=', model_name)], limit=1)
    field_id = ir_model_fields_obj.search([('name', '=', field_name), ('model_id', '=', model_id.id)], limit=1)

    return field_id.field_description
```